# Python Bokeh - How to update calculation results in Data Table using Slider?

Tags: python, slider, bokeh

I have a list of data and I want to run a number of statistics using the first X data points. X could be any integer number between 12 to the maximum # of data. I would like to use a Bokeh Slider to control the value of X. The output is a Bokeh data table. Each statistics represents a column. The issue is that my codes won't update the table.

To simplify my question, I have used [0,1,2,3, ...,49] (50 numbers in sequence) as the list of data. I would like to calculate two basic statistics: (1) Count: number of observations, and (2) Average: average of all observations. The default value of the Slider is at the max point which is 50. If I change the value to 10, I am supposed to see Count = 10 and Average = 5 (= average of 0 to 10).

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Slider, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import column

output_file('Slider_Controlled_Calculation.html')

sample_data = [i for i in range(50)]
max_count = len(sample_data)

partial_data = sample_data[:]

df_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Count', 'Average'])
df_table['Count'] = [len(partial_data)]
df_table['Average'] = [sum(partial_data) / len(partial_data)]
        
mySource = ColumnDataSource(data=df_table)

# Define a callback
def update_table(attr, old, new):
        i = slider.value
        
        partial_data = sample_data[:i]
        
        df_table['Count'] = [len(partial_data)]
        df_table['Average'] = [sum(partial_data) / len(partial_data)]
        
columns = [TableColumn(field=Ci, title=Ci) for Ci in df_table.columns] 

data_table = DataTable(source=mySource, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)
        
# Create a slider
slider = Slider(start = 12, end = max_count, step = 1, value = max_count, title = 'Select Calc Range')

slider.on_change('value', update_table)

layout = column(slider, data_table)

show(layout)
```

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Change `mySource.data` within the callback, not `df_table`.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Could you show me an example? I did the following and it didn't work.

```
def update_table(attr, old, new):
        i = slider.value
        partial_data = sample_data[:i]
        patches = {'Count': [len(partial_data)], 'Average': [sum(partial_data) / len(partial_data)]}
        mySource.patch(patches)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Slider, ColumnDataSource, DataTable, TableColumn

N = 50
sample_data = list(range(N))


def get_new_data(i):
    partial_data = sample_data[:i]
    return dict(Count=[len(partial_data)],
                Average=[sum(partial_data) / len(partial_data)])


ds = ColumnDataSource(data=get_new_data(None))


def update_table(attr, old, new):
    ds.data = get_new_data(new)


columns = [TableColumn(field=Ci, title=Ci) for Ci in ['Count', 'Average']]
data_table = DataTable(source=ds, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

slider = Slider(start=12, end=N, step=1, value=N, title='Select Calc Range')
slider.on_change('value', update_table)

# `show` will not work with Python callbacks. You have to use `bokeh serve`.
curdoc().add_root(column(slider, data_table))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there still a way to show the output in an html file so that I can share it with other ppl who don't have Bokeh installed?

Comment: If you need to be able to run Python callbacks - no. If you make a page without any callbacks or with just JavaScript callbacks (so all `on_change` will become `js_on_change`, same for other similar functions), then yes.